# TCL library returning a string from c++ function

Tags: c++, tcl

I have the following code

```
int redirect_test(ClientData pClientData, Tcl_Interp *pInterp, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string result_str =  "This is the output from the method";
    Tcl_SetObjResult(pInterp, Tcl_NewStringObj(result_str.c_str(), -1));
    return true;
}
```

However when I attempt to use this method in the following way

```
% set m [ redirect_test]
This is the output from the method
% puts $m
can't read "m": no such variable
```

How can I return values from TCL functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your:

```cpp
return true;
```

Tcl command implementations indicate success by returning the C constant `TCL_OK` (= 0) and indicate errors with `TCL_ERROR` (= 1). (There are other other defined result codes, but you're advised to not use them if you're uncertain what they mean.) The `true` gets converted to `1` by the C++ `bool`→`int` cast operator, which is `TCL_ERROR`, making the command fail (and your result string is then the error message).

The fix is trivial. Use this instead:

```cpp
return TCL_OK;
```